# Why does Shell Script to create database via mysql work in terminal but not with exec, passthru, or shell_exec?

Tags: php, mysql, bash, shell

I have the following basic shell script here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# run as root
if [ "`id -u`" -ne 0 ]; then
 exec sudo "$0" "$@"
 exit 99
fi

# dbname mandatory
if [ -z ${1+x} ]; then
  exit 1;
fi

set -a
source /path/to/vars.env

dbhost=${dbhost:=localhost}

dbname="$1"

mysql --defaults-extra-file=$dbcnf_path<<EOF
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $dbname;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON $dbname.* TO '$dbuser'@'$dbhost';
ALTER DATABASE $dbname CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
EOF

echo "Database $dbname was processed."
```

I have a `vars.env` file that just sets the `dbcnf_path` (full directory path to a config.cnf file), `dbuser`, and `dbhost` variable values.

The `config.cnf` file looks like this:

```
[client]
user = "user"
password = "mypassword"
host = "localhost"
```

I have edited `/etc/sudoers` file to allow this .sh file to even run as root (in case that is a problem, which shouldn't be I don't think cause it just accessing mysql).

The php code that executes this (I have tried all ways:  `passthru`, `shell_exec`, and finally `exec` none of them create the database) is as follows:

```
<?php 
    $dbName = 'dbNameTest';
    $cmd = './mysql_test.sh ' . $dbName;
    $data = exec($cmd, $output);
?>
```

Not sure why the database will not be created.  Any ideas how this might need to be changed in order to work via php with exec, shell_exec, or even passthru?  I'm not sure why it's not working, seems a bit odd unless that was intentional to not allow apache to update the database via php in a shell script.  I've just recently updated bash to the newest version and mysql is running version 8.x.x if that helps.

Comment: Why not create the database from within PHP using PHP

Comment: yes, I can do that, but didn't think this would be such a problem in a shell script.

Comment: I suggest adding `set -eux` as the second line in your bash script. This can help debugging it. Refer to the bash manual for these options.

Comment: Ok, strange but that helped me within the php error logs to output this:  ` mysql: command not found` was mysql removed from the newest bash when executed in a shell script or something?  or do I have to also add this in my $PATH perhaps?  Running on macOS Big Sur

Comment: Exported the `$PATH` `/usr/local/mysql/bin` in ~/.bash_profile and sourced the ~/.bash_profile file in the shell script and it's now working properly:  `source ~/.bash_profile`. Apparently that needed to be done even thought it already existed in the $PATH